# Context Sensitive Help in pure E4 Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4, context-sensitive-help

I'm new to Eclipse E4 RCP and am looking for some guidance on how to implement a light-weight context-sensitive help solution in a pure E4 Eclipse RCP application.  I'm hoping to have this work in a similar format to other applications that I've seen but are authored in Eclipse RCP 3.x, that is, in a window as part of the E4 RCP application, and not launching an external browser.

Any suggestions on where I might find some definitive information on this E4 Context-Sensitive Help Implementation / functionality?

Any suggestions on tutorials would be most welcomed.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Marv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The e4 code defines an `EHelpService` service, but there is no standard implementation of this service.

So basic e4 code has no help system available.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply.  Any suggestions on how to proceed as we'll need an interactive Help system with Table of contents.... Am considering using CHM files and navigating the microsoft HTML help app, based upon part id to be context sensitive...

Comment: There is an [Eclipse forums post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1067847/) which suggests it is possible to include most of the 3.x help system in an e4 app without too much trouble. I have not looked at this.

Comment: Thanks... I'll have a look.

Comment: Checking as the answer as we're using 4.4 and have implemented another manual means of achieving help through specific handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 4.6 M7 added support for context sensitive help:

Support for setting the help ID in Eclipse 4 application:
https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M7/

For this to work, I would assume that the help system will work with E4.

Comment: They added support for setting the help ids, but they haven't added an implementation of EHelpSystem.

Answer (score 0):

E4 defines an `EHelpService`, as greg-449 described. But by default there no service registered in context. You can register a EHelpService by your self with an own or the 3.x implementation.

```
bundleContext.registerService(EHelpService.class, new HelpServiceImpl(), null);
```